# pjax example not working

Tags: jquery, pjax, plunker

can u help find why pjax is not working?

https://plnkr.co/edit/CfB9rIKP7EknVNDiYZpR?p=preview

after i click on a link, it just goes to the page (as normal link)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax/master/jquery.pjax.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
     <div class="container" id="pjax-container">
            Go to <a href="bla.html">next page</a>.
            </div>
  </body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).pjax('a', '#pjax-container')
});
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Any error in Developer Console?

Comment: may be because of `$(...).pjax is not a function` error

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your pjax-container in the bla.html page like this :

`<div class="container" id="pjax-container">
            Go to <a href="bla.html">next page</a>.
</div>`

it will works now .

Comment: exactly like bla page
<div class="container" id="pjax-container"> test </div>